# terraform - failing to set environment variable using local-exec

Tags: terraform

As part of terraform run I'm trying to set environment variables on my Linux server using "local-exec" and command (I need to use it with a different application)

```
resource "null_resource" "set_env3" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "export BASTION_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP=2.2.2.2"
  }
}
```

But when running "echo $BASTION_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP" on my Linux server i'm getting an empty output and I also can't locate BASTION_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP parameter when running "printenv"

BTW - I have tried to run the following - but again i can not find the parameter

```
resource "null_resource" "update34" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "env"
   environment = {
       BASTION = "5.5.5.5"
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An export like that just exports the environment variable so it is available to other child processes spawned by the `terraform` process. It doesn't export it to the parent, Unix shell process. In short: this is never going to work. You can't use Terraform `null_resource` to set your local computer's environment variables.

What you need to do is define the value as a Terraform output. Then after you run `terraform apply` you do something like the following:

```
export BASTION_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP=$(terraform output bastion_public_ip --raw)
```

Comment: Sorry, but whatvisnthe difference between putting a string or variable? Just to make it clear, I need that ansible will use the environment varible

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question about strings and variables.